# Sending Flux Response to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I fetch data from list of urls from REST end point in Flux,

```
 Flux.fromIterable(sensorUrls)
                .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .map(url -> webClient.get()
                        .uri(url)
                        .retrieve()
                        .bodyToFlux(Object.class)
                        .retry()
                        .subscribe(this::sendMessage)
                ).subscribe();
```

The send message method need to be send data to Kafka system.

My Kafka config is as below,

```
 public static KafkaSender<String, String> createKafkaSender(){
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "sample-producer");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        SenderOptions<String, String> senderOptions = SenderOptions.create(props);
        return KafkaSender.create(senderOptions);
    }
```

and send message method is,

```
 private void sendMessage(Object data) {
        Flux<ProducerRecord<Integer, String>> flux = Flux.just(new ProducerRecord<>("test-topic", 2, gson.toJson(data)));
        kafkaSender.createOutbound()
                .sendTransactionally(flux) // ISSUE
                .then()
                .doOnError(a -> logger.error("error"))
                .doOnSuccess(a -> logger.error("success"));
        }
    }
```

The compiler error shows me,

```
Required type: Publisher <? extends Publisher<? extends ProducerRecord<String, String>>>
Provided: Flux<ProducerRecord<Integer, String>>
```

Any suggestion or help to convert to Publisher type to make it work?

Comment: If you are sending just 1 record, can you use `send` method?
`sendTransactionally` is for `Flux<Flux<T>>` - for group of records.

Comment: I'm sending streaming data continuously.